# Change post order on archive to be displayed by most commented being ignored by theme

Tags: pre-get-posts

I'm trying to change my archive pages to order by most commented however due to my theme this is getting ignored I think.

This is the code I've put in my custom functions file, but it isn't changing the order.

```
add_action ( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) 
{
    if (  $query->is_archive()
         && !is_admin()
         && $query->is_main_query()

    ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'comment_count' );
    }
});
```

This code in my themes functions I think is making it so my custom code isn't being run:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpcc_custom_posts_oderby' ) ) {
    function wpcc_custom_posts_oderby( $query ) {
        if ( ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) || ( $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) ) {
            $orderby = get_theme_mod( 'wpcc_general_post_orderby' );
            if( !$orderby ): $orderby = 'date'; endif;
            $order = get_theme_mod( 'wpcc_general_post_order' );
            if( !$order ): $order = 'DESC'; endif;

            if( ! function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) || ( function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) && ! is_woocommerce() ) ) {
                $query->set( 'orderby', $orderby );
                $query->set( 'order', $order );
            }
        }
    }

    add_action('pre_get_posts','wpcc_custom_posts_oderby');
}
```

Is there a way I should write my custom code to override the themes?

thanks

Comment: It looks like your code works as you expected, it just runs earlier than the themes function so the result gets overwritten, like following a cake recipe backwards. Your problem is order/timing

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this custom action-hook.

```
add_action('init', function(){
    remove_action('pre_get_posts','wpcc_custom_posts_oderby');;
});
```